# How to express this code mathematically?

Tags: programming

Any programmer can explain how to express this code in math terms?

```
public static int px32(int p){
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i = i + 32) { h++; }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? And what do you think? Have you tried for a few different values of $p$ and seen what you get? Can you describe the result in words?

Comment: I know it's a simple division, but I'm aiming to increase the performance of a renderer (2D tile based).

I tried if(p <= 0){ return 0; } return p / 32; but did not give the same result.

Comment: $\#\{ i \in \mathbb{N} : i < p \land \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, i = 32k \}
= \#\{ k \in \mathbb{N} : k < \frac{p}{32} \} = \lfloor\frac{p+31}{32}\rfloor$ (assume $p \ge 0$).

Comment: Still necessary use if(p <= 0) { return 0; }

Any way for no need use?

Comment: $\text{return (p<0) ? 0 : ((p+31)>>5);}$ this is essentially achille hui's retranslated code.

Comment: zwim, it works. Retranslate the Rócherz with max in answer below, please. xD

Comment: It is the same, calculating ceil(x) value is the same as calculating floor(x+31) value. And shifting by $5$ is the same as dividing by $32$. I don't think there is much more efficient than that, considering that the compilo will much probably also optimize the ? : ternary operator.

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing the thread so far, the code above (along with a `if(p <= 0) { return 0; }`) computes
\begin{matrix}
&{\rm R\acute{o}cherz} &\text{achille hui}\\
h={}&\left\lceil\dfrac{\max\{0,p\}}{32}\right\rceil &=\left\lfloor\dfrac{\max\{0,p\}+31}{32}\right\rfloor & \qquad \text{for } p \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{matrix}
However, since $32 =2^5$ is a power of $2$, perhaps the fastest way to compute $h$ is (zwim):

`return (p<0) ? 0 : ((p+31)>>5);`.

Comment: Are you sure? I think this is wrong for $p=0$.

Comment: It's give me the same result of the for loop.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks, I was stucked between $1+\left\lfloor\dfrac{p}{32}\right\rfloor$ and $\left\lceil\dfrac{p}{32}\right\rceil$.

Comment: Aren't we all, from time to time? :)

Comment: Still necessary use if(p <= 0) { return 0; } Any way for no need use?

Comment: @JonathanCosta:  $h=\left\lceil\dfrac{\max\{0,p\}}{32}\right\rceil$.